# Vertical align all(!) elements in TD?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a simple `table` with 1 `TD` with   `vertical-align:middle;`. This `TD` contains an `Image` :

```css
table
{
  border:solid 1px red;
  width:300px;
}

td
{
  height:100px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:100%;
  border:solid 1px green;
}
img
{
  height:43px;width:43px;
}

span
{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8/>
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src='http://static.jsbin.com/images/favicon.png'/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Everything is Ok and the `IMG` is  vertical-aligned.

**But** If I add another elements after that Image ( a `span` for example ) :

```css
table
{
  border:solid 1px red;
  width:300px;
}

td
{
  height:100px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:100%;
  border:solid 1px green;
}
img
{
  height:43px;width:43px;
}

span
{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8/>
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src='http://static.jsbin.com/images/favicon.png'/>
          <span>aaa</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Question**

Doesn't the vertical align of the TD should vertical align **all** its childs ?

How can I make the `span` to be centered **as well** ?

NB

I don't want to add another `TD` , nor using `float` with padding/margin. IE8+.

## edit:

Desired result  :

[image]

Comment: Does the span have a fixed height (or) will it increase?

Comment: @Harry The span does have a fixed height ( let's say an upper limit) and it wont increase. it's a title.

Comment: You can check if the solution fits. Although some one down voted without a reason. :)

Comment: Here a solution => https://stackoverflow.com/a/57590933/2736742

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> **Question**
>   Doesn't the vertical align of the TD should vertical align all its childs ?

**NO**.
When you apply `vertical-align` to `td`, it is only applied to `td`, and is **not** inherited by any of its children.

> If i have a TD with only span in it - it will vertical align. If I had a TD with only IMG inside it - it will also align.

This is because of the way `vertical-align` for `td` works. The total height of the cell i.e `td` is calculated and **the whole cell** is aligned vertically.

If there is a single `img`, then the height of `td` is same as that of `img`, so it **seems** that `vertical-align` for `img` is also `middle`. But actually, the `td` is vertically aligned to the middle with the `img` as `vertical-align : baseline`

Same is the case when there is a single `span`.

> but if i have both - it doesn't. why is that ?

Because now, the `height` of `td` is the combined `height` of both `img` + `span`. So, actually, `td` is vertically aligned in the middle, but not `img` and `span`.

> How can I make the span to be centered as well ?

You need to apply this CSS :

```
td > * {
    vertical-align : middle;
}
```

This will apply the CSS to all the children.

Check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vXfWV/) for a better picture.

Hope, this answers your question.

Comment: Are you saying that in my first picture , the img is aligned to baseline ? according to this , if i have 2 different jsfiddle , 1 for img and 1 for span , they should overlap in the alignment...

Comment: Yes, the `img` is aligned to baseline. You can inspect the `img` element for the `vertical-align` property ;)

Comment: Well it is **not** aligned both to the baseline : http://i.stack.imgur.com/E0LmR.png

Comment: Check my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vXfWV/). You can see the CSS property fetched through jQuery.

Comment: And as for your picture, make sure you've reset all the `margin` and `padding`. Looks good to me though.

Comment: Im getting crazy....why does this text is not aligned ? http://jsbin.com/AlapaNI/24/edit

Comment: That is some weird problem with `webkit` based browsers. Try that in Firefox. Check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880459/vertical-alignment-text-in-container-webkit-vs-firefox).

Comment: You can write `vertical-align: middle` property by using `bootstrap` class `align-middle` as well

Answer (score 8):

You can just use `vertical-align: middle;` to your span

```
img
{
  height:43px;width:43px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span
{
  vertical-align:middle;
  display: inline;
  
}
```

[your jsbin](http://jsbin.com/AlapaNI/4/)

---

As per comment

---

You may think as if td is given `vertical-align: middle;` then it should align all the contents inside this but having an image and a span in which browser is understanding the image is what? : is this inline or inline-block, so you need to set display: inline or inline-block; Then you may see its working only applying display property for image. [demo](http://jsbin.com/AlapaNI/7/)

**Edit**

img tag : source: [display inline vs inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/img-elements-block-level-element-or-inline-element)

They are "block" elements in that they have a width and a height.

It's true, they are both - or more precisely, they are "inline block" elements. This means that they flow inline like text, but also have a width and height like block elements.

[Also check this:](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements)

**Replaced Elements**

> A replaced element is any element whose appearance and dimensions are defined by an external resource. Examples include images ( tags), plugins ( tags), and form elements (, , , and  tags). All other elements types can be referred to as non-replaced elements.
>
> Replaced elements can have intrinsic dimensions—width and height values that are defined by the element itself, rather than by its surroundings in the document. For example, if an image element has a width set to auto, the width of the linked image file will be used. Intrinsic dimensions also define an intrinsic ratio that’s used to determine the computed dimensions of the element should only one dimension be specified. For example, if only the width is specified for an image element—at, say, 100px—and the actual image is 200 pixels wide and 100 pixels high, the height of the element will be scaled by the same amount, to 50px.
>
> Replaced elements can also have visual formatting requirements imposed by the element, outside of the control of CSS; for example, the user interface controls rendered for form elements.
>
> In an inline formatting context, you can also think of a replaced element as being one that acts as a single, big character for the purposes of wrapping and layout. A width and height can be specified for replaced inline elements, in which case the height of the line box in which the element is positioned is made tall enough to accommodate the replaced element, including any specified box properties.

Comment: Doesn't the vertical align of the TD **should** vertical align all its childs ? (p.s. span & Img  are inline by default)

Comment: vertical-align is needed to be displayed inline.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. ( your last comment) can you elaborate so me and others could learn from it ?

Comment: I mean : IMG is inline by default. so why does putting verticalalign to the TD is not  working on all childs ? can you explain this ?

Comment: No! img is not inline by default.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a JS fiddle solution

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cc84E/)

Here's the css

```
  table
{
  border:solid 1px red;
  width:300px;
}

td
{
  height:100px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:100%;
  border:solid 1px green;
}
img
{
  display: inline;
height: 43px;
width: 43px;
  position: relative !important;
float: left;
}

span
{
  height: auto !important;
width: 80%;
float: right;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle !important;
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the down vote as I can see a lot of people have been down voted by -1 . please try and provide a reason as it is suggested by SO.

Comment: Probably because `vertical-align: middle;` is all you need on the `<img>` class. I didn't downvote you, but it looks like you did too much work for something so simple.

Comment: tried my level best to bring it to center. Was actually firebugging the thing. So did not give a second look on what to keep . May be this will help if just some extra styles might be present :)

Comment: Some one down voted every one serially . maybe :) Who cares just need a proper explanation . :) cause the answer is correct as far as fiddle says :)

Answer (score 4):

In all the cases, the `vertical-align: middle;` on the `td` does what is expected of it. That is, align the `td` to the center of that row and the entire contents of the `td` to the vertical middle (by default) leaving equal spaces at the top and the bottom.

> **Here is what the [W3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout) says about** `vertical-align: middle`:
>
> The center of the cell is aligned with the center of the rows it spans.
>
> [image]

**Row height calculation:**

> The height of a 'table-row' element's box is calculated once the user agent has all the cells in the row available: it is the maximum of the row's computed 'height', the computed 'height' of each cell in the row, and the minimum height (MIN) required by the cells.
>
> In CSS 2.1, the height of a cell box is the minimum height required by the content. The table cell's 'height' property can influence the height of the row (see above), but it does not increase the height of the cell box.
>
> Cell boxes that are smaller than the height of the row receive extra top or bottom padding.

As a result of the above, the height of the `tr` and the `td` becomes 100px but the cell box takes up only the amount of height required by the contents (`img` height = 43px). Now since the Cell box is smaller than the row height, extra padding is added like shown in Box 5 of the image above and thus makes the contents also get aligned to the middle.

---

**TD has only image:**

When there is only an `img`, the content height is equal to the height of the `img`. So it gets positioned to the middle.

[image]

As can be seen in the above image, this does not require a `vertical-align: middle` on the `img` explicitly because the `td` aligns its contents to the middle.

---

**TD has only inline data:**

When the `td` has only a `span` or `span` plus an inline `div`, the height of the content is equal to the default `line-height` for text (or any specified `line-height`). In this case also, the `td` aligns it correctly.

[image]

When the text content goes beyond the first line (refer to the demo), you can see that the `td` automatically pushes the `first-line` (marked in cyan background) upwards to ensure that the contents on the whole is aligned to the middle (not just a single line).

---

**TD has an image and a span:**

When we put an `img` and a `span` (inline text) within the `td`, the content height becomes equal to the height of the `img` plus the `line-height` of the second and subsequent lines.

In this situation, there are two possible cases as described below:

**Case 1 -** `img` **tag has no** `vertical-align` **specified**

In this case, the `img` is aligned to the `baseline` (default). Then the `td` aligns the entire content to the middle. This means the `td` leaves around **28.5px (= (100-43)/2) gap** at the top and the bottom of the content. Again, the `vertical-align` on `td` does the job, it puts the contents in the middle (that is, leave equal gap on top and bottom). But the text gets pushed down because `img` height is more.

[image]

If we reduce the `img` height to less than the line height (say 10px), we can see that even with `img` + `span` it gets aligned to the middle.

---

**Case 2 -** `img` **tag has** `vertical-align: middle`

In this case also `vertical-align` on the `td` does the same as what it did for Case 1. However, the text in this case is [near the middle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) because the `img` is also aligned to the `middle` of the line.

[image]

```css
table {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
td {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
img {
  height: 43px;
  width: 43px;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
.one td + td img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.three td + td img {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
.four img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.five img + img{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
td:first-line {
  background-color: cyan;
}
div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class='one'>
    <td>
      <img src='http://static.jsbin.com/images/favicon.png' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src='http://static.jsbin.com/images/favicon.png' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='two'>
    <td>
      <div>aaa</div>
      <span>aaa</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>aaa</div>
      <span>aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='three'>
    <td>
      Case 1
      <img src='http://static.jsbin.com/images/favicon.png' />
      <span>Image + Span</span> 
    </td>
    <td>
      Case 1
      <img src='http://static.jsbin.com/images/favicon.png' />
      <span>Image + Span</span> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='four'>
    <td>
      Case 2
      <img src='http://static.jsbin.com/images/favicon.png' />
      <span>Image + Span</span> 
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src='http://static.jsbin.com/images/favicon.png' />
      <span>Image + Span + more text.......</span> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='five'>
    <td>
      Case 3
      <img src='http://static.jsbin.com/images/favicon.png' />
      <img src='http://static.jsbin.com/images/favicon.png' />
      <span>Image + Span text...</span> 
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src='http://static.jsbin.com/images/favicon.png' />
      <span>Image + Span + more text.......</span> 
    </td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: What about nikhil's answer which states that it is the td which is aligned and not its content

Comment: Harry , your first long comment has a contradiction . There is td and content . No cell . Leave it alone it's just confusing .... Now - as far as i understood - the img stays still without any align ( default which is baseline) and the td itself is verticaly aligned to the max content (!!!)height of the td . Now am i right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The way I always use it is `td` = cell. I assume that is the same way Nikhil used it also judging from *height of the cell i.e td*. Coming to the second part. Yes, you are right. `vertical-align: middle` on `td` aligns contents of the `td` to the middle. So if for example `td` height is 100px, we have two lines of `20px` height each, we would have a 30px ((100-40)/2) space on top and bottom. The `img` or any other element within the `td` doesn't get aligned to the middle of the line that holds it unless `vertical-align` is set for it also. (Btw, thanks for the bounty :))

Comment: You are doing it again :-). Settings vertical align middle to the td - aligns the td(!! Not its content!) to the middle of its max content height .Please confirm. What im saying is that there is a difference if im standing and the room aligns to my stumach  ... Vs ... Im aligning to the middle height of my room

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38070/discussion-between-harry-and-royi-namir)

Answer (score 3):

Just add `vertical-align:middle;` to your img style?

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/AlapaNI/15/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
table
{
  border:solid 1px red;
  width:300px;
}

td
{
  height:100px;  
  width:100%;
  border:solid 1px green;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:100px;
}
img
{
  height:43px;width:43px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AZGc7/1/)

just add this class:

```
td *{
  vertical-align:middle
}
```

## Edit:

question is why when you add a pic to the `td` text goes bottom of pic and not any more middle of td.

this is my answer:

when you set `td` `vertical-align` to `middle` it should not set all content `vertical-align` to `middle`, they are still `baseline`. and when you add a pic to the text, the line height rise to the height of image and text is bottom of this height, so you need to set `vertical-align` to `middle` for fix this problem.

here you can see what i said: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AZGc7/9/)

*and sorry about my bad english*

Comment: you dont explain nothing and you answer to what i already know. read the question again.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: the image's `vertical-align` default value is `baseline`.

Comment: but i set vertical align to the td which should vertical aliugn all its content ! read my bounty description.

Comment: @RoyiNamir no it is not true. a child just get the parent attribute value when default value is `inherit`. look at this: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AZGc7/5/)

Comment: You dont understand. look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AZGc7/6/) this is pure img which is aligned. now look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AZGc7/7/) :  this is 2 labels which also aligned. **together they are not**.

Comment: You don't have to add an extra class to the stylesheet. It's not much work to do so, but it's not necessary. You simply need to add `vertical-align: middle;` to the '<img>' class.

Comment: @webfrogs: if you want to set all content in the middle so you have to add extra class, for example two word with different `font-size`. look at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/AZGc7/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/JFVNq/

The reason is spans are treated as inline so you need to make them block.

CSS for the span:

```
td.vert span
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we are all nearly there but

```
td img,
td span {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

seems to work.

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/djgLi)

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This **CSS attribute doesn't go on any other kinds of elements**. When the novice developer applies vertical-align to normal block elements (like a standard ) most browsers set the value to inherit to all inline children of that element.

You simply need to add `vertical-align: middle` to the `<img>` class.

Your CSS should look like this...

```
table
{
  border:solid 1px red;
  width:300px;
}

td
{
  height:100px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:100%;
  border:solid 1px green;
}
img
{
  height:43px;width:43px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can view the <kbd>[**Sample Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/vebR4/)</kbd>...

Answer (score -1):

Just move your vertical-align: middle from the span to the image.

The image will align itself on the text; works better than the opposite ;)

```
img
{
  height:43px;width:43px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZnpNF/1/