# How to center td tags in odoo QWeb

Tags: odoo, qweb

How i can center a value in table , the table contain a column that contain the same value in each raw, i need to print only one value in all the raw and not print the value for each raw.
I try to customize print rapport in odoo sale module.

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: please add more information

Comment: You really have to work on your questions. Try to give a simple example. It's a table so that shouldn't be so difficult. What have you tried so far? Which part of the report's QWeb template has to be changed for your requirement. Try to use as less images as possible. Inline code is much better in questions.

Comment: And another thing about your actual question: it's contradictory. First you ask about centering of `td`s but then you ask about a so called `rowspan`. What do you really want to do?

Comment: i need to center one value in rowspan, if i use rowspan without odoo i have value centered hiirizontal and vertical, but if i use rowspan in Qweb, the value is centered only horizzontal not vertical, that mean the value is in row 1  of column that contain many rows!!!

Comment: You need to show an example of your code and an example of the results you get currently. Please update your question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment is a pain in the butt in html, it is not very odoo related, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941108/vertical-align-all-elements-in-td). If you could do what you want in HTML, then style the odoo form respectfully. But beware, changing default rendering of forms is not a good idea at all!